# OpenLayers saving GeoJSON features in different projection

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, geojson

I've used ol.interactin.Draw to draw and save features in GeoJSON format. But the drawn features are stored in EPGS:3857 and my preference is WGS 84. For that, I've used this snippet code to apply dataProjection and featureProjection properties but nothing has been changed.

```
draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
        source: vectorSource,
        type: selectedType.value
    });

    draw.on('drawend', function (evt) {

        var extraFeature = evt.feature; 
        var features = vectorSource.getFeatures();
        var allFeatures = features.concat(extraFeature);

        featuresGeoJSON = parser.writeFeatures(allFeatures, {
            dataProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
            featureProjection: 'EPSG:4326'
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo, it is `EPSG` (not `EPGS`)

Comment: It was a mistake but the problem was not related to that. I switched dataProjection with featureProjection and it worked fine.